# How to hold a thread till MQTT message has arrived

Tags: java, multithreading, mqtt, paho

In my app im sending a message via Paho MQTT and i have to wait for a response before sending  new message.

e.g.:

```
while (!exit){
  sendMessage(); //sends message via Paho MQTT 
  myMqttConnection.run() //starts a thread to wait for Response via Paho MQTT
  //what to do to hold this thread till a message has arrived?
}
```

sendMessage() and myMqttConnection are 2 different topics in case that matters

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to tackle this, given the limited information that you have provided.

If you *have* to spawn a thread in the `myMqttConnection.run()` code, you need a way for your Threads to wait for each other.

If you are happy with old-skool code, a shared guard object and a wait/notify mechanism would do it. The more modern way to do this is with something like a CyclicBarrier.

Otherwise, if you are spawning a thread in `myMqttConnection.run()`, but then you wait for it to complete, you have to question why you are spawning a thread..? Why not just rename `run()` to `read()` and return the message from the `read()` message.

Comment: Since i am using the paho library by eclipse i do net specifically spawn a new thread, rather the libary does. I wish i would be able to not use a separat thread.

Thanks for your reply, i am going to try the CyclicBarrier way